# How can I automate the upload of a successful TFS build to the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tfs, automation, azure-devops, pipeline

I want to build a pipeline to automate the upload to the chrome web store after every successful build from TFS. Any leads would be really helpful.

Comment: This article should helps: [Using the Chrome Web Store Publish API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api)

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT Sorry for my delayed response. Your answer was really heplful. Thanks for that.

Comment: Thank you @MarTin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike [Google Play](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play) contains a set of deployment tasks which allow you to automate the release, promotion and rollout of app updates to the Google Play store from your CI environment.

We do not have any build-in task or extension in TFS/Azure DevOps which handle the upload process to the Chrome Web Store.

You need to customize by yourself. Since the artifacts are generated through build, you can publish/deploy to chrome store by **using release**:

1. Create a new [release definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/)
2. Link that build as release artifacts
3. Write a script  [using the Chrome Web Store Publish API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api) programmatically creating, updating, and publishing items in the Chrome Web Store
4. Add powershell task to invoke the script
5. Other settings
6. Start/trigger release